# Sample Covariance of a Data Matrix

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix, matrix

[image: Data Matrix]

[image]

I am having a hard time interpreting the sample covariance of this data matrix. From what I understand, the rows of the data matrix X are x1, x2,...xn - given by the transpose. Now, I am slightly confused with what sigma hat is supposed to represent, and how it relates to COV(Xj, Xj'). Furthermore, I am unsure as to what j' is. Any explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There is no "E hat" in these formulas: do you mean *Sigma* hat?  It's just a name given to the covariance: that's what the $=$ sign generally means.  Since it's a matrix, it requires two subscripts: $j$ and $j^\prime$ are their names.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - sigma hat. However, how does the first sigma hat relate to the second sigma hat? Is the first equation relating to a 1 dimensional vector, and the second is related to a matrix?

Comment: They are identical: the second equation merely is explicit about the subscripts while the first equation uses a vector notation.